# Is it possible to hand over the new development version to release:perform?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I want to hook in the release:perform step and execute some custom actions. This works like a charm - the only thing that is currently not working is to handover the new development version to the release:perform call. The configuration I have is something like this. I tried to replace the ??? with project.version but that is not the correct version I'm looking for.

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.3</version>
           <configuration>
                    <!-- During release:perform, enable a special "mySpecialReleaseProfile" profile -->
              <releaseProfiles>mySpecialReleaseProfile</releaseProfiles>
              <!-- how to hand over the new development version to release:perform -->
              <arguments>-DtheNewDevelopmentVersion=${???} ${arguments}</arguments>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

It works if I handover the developmentVersion manually with `-DdevelopmentVersion` and use the following configuration but I want this to work independent if the developmentVersion is handed over as `-DdevelopmentVersion=xyz`, entered manually by the user or increased automatically by the release plugin.

```
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.5.3</version>
           <configuration>
                    <!-- During release:perform, enable a special "mySpecialReleaseProfile" profile -->
              <releaseProfiles>mySpecialReleaseProfile</releaseProfiles>
              <!-- how to hand over the new development version to release:perform -->
              <arguments>-DtheNewDevelopmentVersion=${developmentVersion} ${arguments}</arguments>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hm..Maybe I misunderstand a thing. The property for maven-release-plugin is `developmentVersion`? Or what is the problem?

Comment: sorry if I was not clear. Handing over  `<arguments>-DdevelopmentVersion=${developmentVersion} ${arguments}</arguments>` did not work - I got a recursion error. But that is not the problem. I want to handover the developmentVersion that is used by the maven release plugin.